# Extensible Records and Higher Order Functions

Tags: compiler-errors, functional-programming, elm, higher-order-functions, records

I want to specify a type for records that have an `id` field whose type is a `Uuid`. So, I'm using extensible records. The type looks like this:

```
type alias WithId a = { a | id : Uuid }
```

So far, so good. But then I went to create a `Json.Encoder` -- that is, a function of type `WithId a -> Value` -- for this type. I need a way to encode the underlying value, so I want to take a first argument of type `a -> Value`. Since I know `a` is a record, I can safely assume it is encoded to a JSON object, even though Elm doesn't expose the data types for `Value`.

However, when I create such a function, I get a compile error:

```
    The argument to function `encoder` is causing a mismatch.

27|             encoder a
                        ^
Function `encoder` is expecting the argument to be:

    a

But it is:

    WithId a

Hint: Your type annotation uses type variable `a` which means any type of value
can flow through. Your code is saying it CANNOT be anything though! Maybe change
your type annotation to be more specific? Maybe the code has a problem? More at:
<https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/type-annotations.md>

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

I'm confused. Isn't something of type `WithId a` going to contain all the fields of `a`, and therefore shouldn't `WithId a` be an `a` through the `type alias` structural typing?

What am I missing? Why isn't the type alias of `WithId a` allowing me to use a `WithId a` as an instance of `a`, even though it is defined as `{a|...}`?

**ADDENDUM**

I've marked an answer below (which amounts to "You just can't do that, but here's what you're supposed to be doing."), but I'm still a bit unsatisfied. I guess I'm confused by the use of the term `type alias`. My understanding was that records were always a `type alias`, because they were explicitly specifying a subset of fields among all possible fields...but the underlying type was still the unifying record type (akin to a JS Object).

I guess I don't understand why we say:

```
type alias Foo = { bar : Int }
```

instead of

```
type Foo = { bar : Int }
```

The former implies to me that any record with `{ bar : Int }` is a `Foo`, which would imply to me that `{a|bar:Int}` is both of the same type as `a` and a `Foo`. Where am I wrong here? I'm confused. I feel like I'm not grokking records.

**ADDENDUM 2**

My goal is not just to have a type `WithId` that specifies there is an `.id` on a field, but rather to have two types: `Foo` and `WithId Foo` where `Foo` has structure `{ bar:Int }` and `WithId Foo` has structure `{ bar:Int, id:Uuid}`.  I'd then like to also have a `WithId Baz`, `WithId Quux`, etc., etc., with a single encoder and single decoder function for `WithId a`.

The basic issue is that I have persisted and non-persisted data, which have the exact same structure, except that once something is persisted, I have an id. And want I type-level guarantees that records are persisted in certain cases, so `Maybe` doesn't work.

Comment: For the record, I've given up on extensible records to solve my problem and just used a type alias around a tuple of `(Uuid, a)`. Not as nice an API as I'd like, but it works.  I'm still confused why I can't do what I wanted to do.

Comment: Looks like this is an old and recurring conversation in the Elm community: https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1308#issuecomment-197170407

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning about what you know about a `WithId a` value and what you should therefore be able to do with it (i.e. treat it as an `a`) is logically sound, but Elm’s support for extensible records just doesn't play with the type system in a way that permits that. Indeed, Elm’s extensible record types are specifically designed *not* to allow access to the full record.

What extensible records are designed for is to declare that a function will only access certain fields of a record, and the compiler then enforces that constraint:

```
type alias WithId a =
    { a | id : Uuid }

isValidId : WithId a -> Bool
isValidId withId =
    -- can only access .id

updateId : WithId a -> WithId a
updateId withId =
    { withId |
        id = -- can only access .id
    }
```

When used to write functions that work on a small slice of a large program model, for example, this provides powerful guarantees about what a given function is able to do. Your `updateUser` function, for example, can be constrained only to access the `user` field of your model, rather than having free reign to access perhaps dozens of fields in your model. When you are later trying to debug an unexpected change to your model, these constraints help you quickly rule out many functions as being responsible for that change.

For more concrete examples of the above, I recommend Richard Feldman’s elm-europe 2017 talk https://youtu.be/DoA4Txr4GUs (see 23:10 in that video for the part showing extensible records).

I had the same excitement followed by confused disappointment when I first learned about extensible records, but in hindsight I think that comes from my deeply ingrained Object Oriented Programming instincts. I saw “extensible” and my brain jumped straight to “inheritance”. But Elm doesn't implement extensible records in a way that can support type inheritance.

The real intended purpose of extensible records, as illustrated in the examples above, is to constrain functions’ access to only a subset of a large record type.

As for your specific use case, I'd suggest starting with an `Encoder` for each of your data types, and if you want to reuse the implementation of an ID encoder, call a shared `idEncoder` function from within each of your encoders.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and I've marked it as the answer, but I guess I'm confused by the use of the term "type alias". My understanding was that records were always a "type alias", because they were explicitly specifying a subset of fields among all possible fields...but the underlying type was still the unifying record type (akin to a JS Object).

I guess I don't understand why we say:

    type alias Foo = { bar : Int } 

instead of 

    type Foo = { bar : Int }

The former implies to me that anything with { bar : Int } is a Foo. Where am I wrong here? I'm confused.

Comment: That comment got really long, so I added an addendum to the question above.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing we know about an instance of `WithId a`is that is has a `.id` field. If we encode a `WithId a` the best we can do is encode the `.id` value.

```
type alias Uuid =
    String

encodeUuid : Uuid -> Value
encodeUuid =
    Encode.string

type alias WithId a =
    { a | id : Uuid }

encode : WithId a -> Value
encode withId =
    encodeUuid withId.id
```

Comment: Your statement isn't quite true. I know more. I also know `WithId a` has all the fields of an `a`, which is an unbound variable and therefore uninteresting on its own...but when I take a function of type `(a -> Value)` and `(WithId a -> Value)`, now I know that I can pass an `a` into the function and get a `Value`. Since `WithId a` has all the fields of `a`, I expected it to be able to be treated as an `a`. That's just a false assumption in Elm. Looks like it's an old point: https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1308#issuecomment-197170407

Answer (score 1):

Reading your addenda and re-reading your question, I believe you actually can achieve what you want with extensible records in Elm.

Here's a little program that does what you're after and compiles just fine:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, pre, text)
import Json.Encode as Json exposing (Value, int, object, string)


main : Html msg
main =
    let
        json =
            Json.encode 2 <|
                encoder recordEncoder record
    in
    pre [] [ text json ]


type alias WithId a =
    { a | id : Int }


type alias Record =
    WithId
        { fieldA : String
        }


record : Record
record =
    { id = 123
    , fieldA = "A"
    }


encoder : (WithId a -> Value) -> WithId a -> Value
encoder recordEncoder value =
    object
        [ ( "id", int value.id )
        , ( "value", recordEncoder value )
        ]


recordEncoder : Record -> Value
recordEncoder record =
    object
        [ ( "fieldA", string record.fieldA ) ]
```

[View on Ellie - The Elm Live Editor](https://ellie-app.com/cCYQkYFRma1/2)

As per my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325100/76951) I'm still pretty sure it won't work out well if you extend this pattern to your whole program, but the nice thing about Elm is that you can try stuff like this and if it doesn't work out, the compiler is there to help you refactor!

…and if you really need to be able to deal with both persisted and non-persisted records in your program, you can do it with just a little repetition in your type aliases:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, pre, text)
import Json.Encode as Json exposing (Value, int, object, string)


main : Html msg
main =
    let
        json =
            Json.encode 2 <|
                encoder recordEncoder record
    in
    pre [] [ text json ]


type alias WithId a =
    { a
        | id : Int
    }


type alias Record a =
    { a
        | fieldA : String
    }


type alias PersistedRecord =
    { id : Int
    , fieldA : String
    }


record : PersistedRecord
record =
    { id = 123
    , fieldA = "A"
    }


encoder : (WithId a -> Value) -> WithId a -> Value
encoder recordEncoder value =
    object
        [ ( "id", int value.id )
        , ( "value", recordEncoder value )
        ]


recordEncoder : Record a -> Value
recordEncoder record =
    object
        [ ( "fieldA", string record.fieldA ) ]
```

[View on Ellie - The Elm Live Editor](https://ellie-app.com/cCYQkYFRma1/3)

To answer this part of your addenda directly:

> I guess I don't understand why we say:
>
> ```
> type alias Foo = { bar : Int }
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> type Foo = { bar : Int }
> ```
>
> The former implies to me that any record with `{ bar : Int }` is a Foo, which would imply to me that `{a|bar:Int}` is both of the same type as `a` and a `Foo`. Where am I wrong here? I'm confused. I feel like I'm not grokking records.

`{ a | bar:Int }` is not a `Foo`, because the `Foo` type alias specifies a fixed set of fields. `Foo` contains a `bar` field *and no other fields*. If you want to say “a record with these fields *and possibly others*”, you need to use the extensible record syntax (`{ a | …fields… }`).

So I think where you're going wrong is in assuming that all record types are extensible. They aren't. When a function says it takes or returns a record with a fixed set of fields, those values will never contain other fields—the compiler guarantees it.

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is that I'm trying to avoid repeating every field in every model twice, just once with an additional `id` field added in. Although I suppose I could do this: `RecordWithId = WithId Record`, so I've at least got type safety, but no meaningful decoder/encoder reuse. That's at least a start.

Comment: I guess my confusion is why records are a `type alias` and not a `type`? If it's explicitly saying there's nothing else, what it is an `alias` of? I guess it's because it is structurally typed, but only if it's an exact match on the number, names, and types of the fields?

Comment: @RobertFischer Yes, I think you're right. I personally think of `type` as introducing entirely new possible values to the compiler, whereas `type alias` just gives a convenient name to a type of which you *could* just create literal values without telling the compiler it has a name. I'm not sure how clear or useful a distinction that is, though.

Comment: It's plenty useful, in that it accurately determines when you use a `type` and when you use a `type alias`. :)